# If list item exists do not append but change the fontcolor

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have this script that appends a list item if it's not allready there.
What i want it to do also is that if the list item does allready exist that it's font color(css)is set to another color.

```
var itemName = userName,
    userFound = false;

$('#msgUserlist li').each(function () {
    if ($(this).text() === itemName) {
        userFound = true;
    }
});

if (userFound === true) {
    ////// at this point i want the fontcolor of the allready existing item be set.///
    return;
} else
    var newNode = document.createElement('li');
    newNode.innerHTML = '<a id="switchtoUser" name="' + userName + '" ' + 'onclick="ajaxChat.getHistory' + '(\'' + userName + '\')"' + ' href="javascript:ajaxChat.sendPrivateMessageWrapper(\'/query ' + userName + '\');">' + userName + '</a>';
    document.getElementById('msgUserlist').appendChild(newNode);
},
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it while looping through the list when you're searching for the user:

```
// ...snip

$('#msgUserlist li').each(function () {
    if ($(this).text() === itemName) {
        userFound = true;
        $(this).css({
            color: "blue" // or whatever
        });
        return;
    }
});

// ...snip
```

Comment: Ok, i'm having difficulty putting it in the context of the code provided. It's looks like the append code that follows also gets executed in a strange way that it gets appended dozens of time. Also with the other solutions provided that's the case.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you do the moment you find it?

```
if ($(this).text() === itemName) {
    userFound = true;
    $(this).css('color', 'red'); // Example: change the color to red
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this would be nicely solved by the Jquery function css()

**HTML**

```
<ul id=msgUserlist>
    <li>Foo</li>
    <li>userName</li>
    <li>tball rulez</li>
</ul>
```

**Javascript**

```
var itemName = 'userName';

$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("#msgUserlist li").each(function() {
        if($(this).text() == itemName )
            $(this).css("color", "red");
    })
})
```

See working example (simple, but can be expanded with the logic you outlined in your question!): http://jsfiddle.net/PGfgv/601/